# Temenos T24 R19 Deployment Error

Tags: aix

I have deployed Temenos T24 R19 on WebSphere with Oracle 12C (ExaData) on AIX platform. From Classic mode, I'm able to login to T24. But in T24 Browser, I'm getting below error.

```
[7/25/19 9:11:56:541 IST] 00000196 BusinessExcep E   CNTR0020E: EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of method "processMessage" on bean "BeanId(TAFJJEE_EAR#TAFJJEE_EJB.jar#BROWSERProcessingBean, null)". Exception data: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/temenos/t24/JF_INITIALISE_CONNECTION_cl
        at com.temenos.tafj.ee.bean.common.AbstractProcessingBean.startTAFJSession(AbstractProcessingBean.java:733)
        at com.temenos.tafj.ee.bean.common.AbstractProcessingBean.processMessage(AbstractProcessingBean.java:187)
        at com.temenos.tafj.sb.OFSProcessingBean.processMessage(OFSProcessingBean.java:130)
```

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have configured the t24 shared library paths in websphere (Classpath).

Your error clearly indicates missing T24 library